# Include Pandas output HTML table (Jupyter) in question

Tags: discussion, support

```
    pub_year    price   categ   rev
bk1 2006         20      fict   10
bk2 2007         60      fict   12
bk3 2008         80      fict   42
```

How do I include the above DataFrame object in a question as the output table from Jupyter as given below (given below is a screenshot)?

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

So, for presentation purposes we include it like this by formatting via the link below.

```
+-----+----------+-------+-------+-----+
|     | pub_year | price | categ | rev |
+-----+----------+-------+-------+-----+
| bk1 |     2006 |    20 | fict  |  10 |
| bk2 |     2007 |    60 | fict  |  12 |
| bk3 |     2008 |    80 | fict  |  42 |
+-----+----------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Link: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

**EDIT 2:**

**But now I think it's not a good Idea. Because people generally use `pd.read_clipboard()` to quickly create dataframe object from the table given in the question. If we use borders then `pd.read_clipboard()` will fail.**

Comment: Uh? You just did? What is the problem?

Comment: Thats an image. I want to include it as an HTML table.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @Stargateur Seems like table is not allowed. Thanks.